# At exactly what rate do staves recharge?

Tags: brogue

I understand that my ?/6 staff of conjuration recharges faster than my ?/3 staff of blinking, but it'd be helpful to know exactly how fast they charge. Is this information documented or known to anyone?

Comment: Which version is this? There is a wand of domination, but no staff of domination in the staff list for version 1.6. A staff of domination would be exceedingly potent, as it were. Did you perhaps mean obstruction/blinking?

Comment: @GraceNote I apologize, I wasn't specifically referring to staves in my inventory - my question is about the recharge rate of staves in general. I know that conjuration and domination are both effects, but I wasn't aware they couldn't both appear on staves.

Comment: Well, there's two different kinds of charge rates, is the issue. If the question is "How much faster does a staff with more charges regain its charges?", then the question would ideally be phrased as such, but if it's "How much faster does a normal staff charge compared to a slow-charge staff?", then it would then be phrased in that fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation on the site,  all staves charge over a certain given timeframe).  This means that staves with more charges seem to charge faster.  I.e. if a staff takes 10 turns to charge to full (regardless of # charges), then one with 3 charges appears to get one charge every three turns, but one with 6 gets 1 charge every 1 and a half, giving the illusion of charging faster.

I looked through the source code, and it appears that the recharge rate depends upon any wisdom bonus you may have.

rechargeIncrement = (int) (10 * pow(1.3, min(27, rogue.wisdomBonus))); 10 if no wisdombonus.

A specific comment within the code indicates that at level 27, items charge to full in one turn.  Staves of Blinking and Obstruction charge at half speed.

Comment: Wisdom isn't a stat you have inherently, it's something gained from rings, and possibly other items.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this in plain english:


Number Of Turns To Recharge One Staff Charge = (???)*(10 * Max Number Of Charges*(1.3*?????????????); 10 if no wisdombonus.

Comment: Problem here is that the number that determines how fast a staff recharges is randomly determined for each item.  Assuming that an item gets a 100 for this value, if the item has 4 charges, you get one back every 25 turns.  If it has 5 charges, you get one every 20 turns (making it seem like it recharges faster).  If the value is random at 120, then those numbers become 30 and 24.  I am having trouble reading through the code (it's in c, and I am trying to read it using Notepad since I don't have a compiler installed for it), but this part seems fairly straightforward.  Final answer: Random

Comment: @Gumbz.  The pow in the calculation is a power statement.  It basically says 1.3 to the nth power, where n is the lower of 27 or wisdomBonus.  So, if you have a wisBonus of 1, final result = 13; 2 = 16; 3 = 21; etc.  But see my comment above on how that effects each item...